# Dialogflow query working in console but not when you use embedded url

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have made a query flow in dialogflow and it has four intent and in the last intent it uses a webhook to get data from server side and displays the result. It is trained automatically and works perfectly in dialogflow console returning response and query answer. The issue is it does not work when I use embedded url. It fails to recognize the name intent and asks (Can you repeat again or fallback intent). I've removed all intents and made query again, there is no similar name intents. Yet it works well in console and not in embedded url.

For the webhook part I've used node.js service.

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By 'embedded url' if you mean Dialogflow Web Demo (DWD), you should keep in mind that DWD can be used only for simple text messages. It does not support messages from webhook or even rich responses. However, if you steel need a web widget to embed your bot to your webpage you either create your own or you should use third party solutions (like Kommunicate). Here's the link [regarding the limitations of DWD](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/web-demo).